# ios observer not working on device but working on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

I am using an observer to track loggedin status of a user, the status is updated to  nsuserdefaults; below is the code

```
 if(loggedInStatusDefault != true){
    defaults.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: loginDefaultsKeys.accessTokenKey, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
 }
```

whenever the value `loginDefaultsKeys.accessTokenKey` is updated, the `observeValueForKeyPath` function is called -

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
   DDLogVerbose("LoggedIn successfully")
   showHomeScreen()
}
```

Inside observeValueForKeyPath, I am calling showHomeScreen() that is dependent on the accessToken that I updated in the userdefaults.

The problem here is, the whole flow/code is working when I run the app on a Simulator, but not working on a ios devicce (tried on iphone 6s plus, iphone 6s running ios 9).

Can anyone help why this is happening? Does observer has something to do with the devices?

Comment: Please define "not working"

Comment: @danh : not working I  meant, the observeValueForKeyPath is not being called when there is a change happened to loginDefaultsKeys.accessTokenKey. And it is not working only on a device, it's working good on simulators